# How to open UITableViewCell by changing height?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to open an UITableViewCell by changing the height to the full screen height instead of doing a standard drill down animation.

i.e. something like this:
https://dribbble.com/shots/2245868--Writer-Article-List

Does anyone have an idea on how to create something like this?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this is merely an ordinary push transition (pushing a detail view controller onto the UINavigationController stack) with a custom transition animation. The "expansion" effect is a clever illusion.

Consider, for example, Apple's Calendar app, which transitions from a year to a month, in a navigation controller, by zooming in.

So, you'll implement `navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:` and the rest follows as usual with custom transition animations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I’ll definitely try this out.